# Regular Expression to matches any email

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

I'm developing a Python application which matches any email address even if that contains at , dot and even white space between words.

Help me to develop the regex to get the expected output

Comment: I think there it doesn't talk about email addresses having (at) dot etc.

Comment: As if RFC-compliant addresses were not [hard enough](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html), you want to add support for spam-unfriendly addresses in a validator? The whole point of spam-unfriendly addresses is to be hard to decode using a computer...

Comment: What if there are two spaces before the 'at'? How do you expect any regular expression to differentiate between, for example, 'blah blah peter at place dot edu' and 'peter jones at place dot edu'? No regex can do this because their form is identical. You would need some extremely clever machine learning to stand a chance at this.

Comment: What about people using other conventions than `joe at example dot com`? E.g `joe -at- example -dot- com` or `joe (at) example (dot) com`...

Comment: I suspect that we have a [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) case here. @SachithDeshanN: what is the *purpose* of your application? If you tell us what you are trying to do at a higher level, we might be able to help you more - as long as you are not making a mail-address harvester, that is.

Comment: Here in the username part of email. there can't be whitespaces.

I mean there will be no "peter jones at place dot edu" like address

I want to get only the addresses like "peterjones at place dot edu"

Comment: The sole purpose of the app is for a python assignment at my uni. I'm a newbie to python and this is the first assignment given for us

Comment: @thkala I dont want to match other conventions. I just need to match this convention since it was the requirement

Comment: @SachithDeshanN: agreed. The critical piece of information missing from your question was that it is a homework assignment. Homework assignments do not have to make sense :-)

Comment: but I tried and still trying to do it, I think homeworks shouldn't be posted without trying at all. Anyway thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an expression like:

```
[\w.+]+(?:@|\s+at\s+|\s*\(at\)\s*)(?:[\w+-]+(?:\.|\s+dot\s+))+\w+
```

Comment: wowwwwww !!! thank you very very much. worked like a charm. Thanks again. You saved my day :)

Comment: @Sachith, np, also updated. (-;